# Find string matching pattern1 but not matching pattern 2

Tags: regex

I am trying to work on a piece of code that will refactor my system.
So I will read all my classes and find every class or object that is called *Manager* using regex.
I want to do that only for the classes I wrote, so I do not want to find `BeanManager` and `EntityManager` classes.

Currently my regex is

```
/([a-zA-Z]*)Manager/
```

This works nice, but `BeanManager` and `EntityManager` are also included.

I've found this kind of question: [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-text-that-doesnt-contain-a-word). In this case the OP wanted to find anything that doesn't match a pattern, but in my case I would like to find everything matching a pattern except if it matches a second pattern

Is there any way I can do that?

Sorry, I forgot the examples

I would like to include things like

> MyManager
>
> myManager
>
> ClientManager
>
> clientManager
>
> testManager
>
> TestManager

but exclude

> BeanManager
>
> EntityManager

Comment: Please include some example of what you want to match, and what you would not like to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word boundaries with a negative look-ahead to exclude the compounds that you want to ignore:

```
\b(?!Bean|Entity)([a-zA-Z]*)Manager\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zE9lZ6/1)

Comment: In most examples here on SO, you will see the use of `^` and `$` anchors, but `\b` is a good replacement when it comes to anchoring a match inside a larger string. Glad it helps.